# non-Lebesgue-measurable subsets of Smith-Volterra-Cantor sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

For the [Smith-Volterra-Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) (or simply SVC) we define an equivalence relation R by making each connected component in SVC an equivalence class.   It is easy to see that the collection of all R-equivalence classes has the cardinality continuum $\aleph_1$.   We know that there is a union of R-equivalence classes that is not Borel.

Is there a union of  R-equivalence classes not Lebesgue measurbale?

Comment: Cardinality of the continuum is not $\aleph_1$, unless you assume the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I do assume the continuum hypothesis in my question.

Comment: I should point out that it is irrelevant that you do for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few remarks to be made here:

1. The cardinality of the continuum is not $\aleph_1$ without assuming the continuum hypothesis.
2. SVC sets are totally disconnected. This means that every equivalence class is in fact a singleton.
3. Every set of positive measure has a subset which is non-measurable. So if the SVC set was not of measure zero, this set would be non-Lebesgue measurable as well.

Comment: Thank you.  But the SVC set is indeed Lebesgue measurable (actually closed) because it is the intersection of a sequence of closed sets.

Comment: I don't get the gist of your comment. I never said it isn't measurable. I said that if the SVC has a **positive** measure then it has a non-measurable subset. If you happened to construct a measure zero SVC set, then every subset would be measurable.